# Use animation on button click?

Tags: java, android, animation

I am trying to use this cool animation called [SmallBang](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/SmallBang)
on my Image button. Here is how my code looks for now:

```
import xyz.hanks.library.SmallBang;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SmallBang smallBang;
private ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    smallBang = SmallBang.attach2Window(this);
    smallBang.bang((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton));
}

public void onSettingsButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
}
```

I want to use that animation and then change to another activity. When i run this code I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

If i remove the smallbang animation, the button and activity change works just fine. What could I do to get the animation working? I've added the library to the Gradle file.

Comment: show `SettingsActivity` code

Comment: @SohailZahid I opened it up and realized I made a small mistake there. Fixes it, now I can change view without errors, but the button animations dont work. I tried Logic's solution (below) and still doesnt work.

Comment: Jr give 3 mins m testing.

Comment: @SohailZahid Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SmallBang mSmallBang;
    private ImageView ImageButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSmallBang = SmallBang.attach2Window(this);

        ImageButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        ImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mSmallBang.bang(v);
                mSmallBang.setmListener(new SmallBangListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd() {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_1">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update your code modification:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SmallBang mSmallBang;
    private ImageView ImageButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSmallBang = SmallBang.attach2Window(this);
        ImageButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    }

    public void onSettingsButtonClick(View view) {
        mSmallBang.bang(view);
        mSmallBang.setmListener(new SmallBangListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if still have issue comment here.

Comment: It works now, but I am wondering, if it is possible to but the code in my "onSettingsButtonClick" method instead of in "onCreate"?

Comment: @CarltonJr. check update section for your code update it needs view for making boon after clicked.

Comment: Can I ask you for a question? If you look at the Github page for the animation,if you scroll down youll find "other method" and the method " public void setColors(int[] newColors)". You can use it as smallband.setColors(new int[]{someInt,Someint,.......}) .Say I wanna use the colow with the hex-code #FF1122. How do I convert that into int for that method? Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120247/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-carlton-jr).

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
import xyz.hanks.library.SmallBang;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SmallBang smallBang;
private ImageButton imageButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    smallBang = SmallBang.attach2Window(this);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    smallBang.bang(view,new SmallBangListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd() {
        onSettingsButtonClick(imageButton);
    }
    });
}

public void onSettingsButtonClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesnt show the animation, and also as soon as I open the app, it "clicks" the button and changes the view instantly. any suggestions?

Comment: I think in XML you might have written onclick for the button. Please remove that